# GTK# Mono - Retrieving the size of a fixed container or the width of a horizontal pane

Tags: mono, gtk#

I'm developing a video player of sorts that includes an mplayer widget running inside a fixed container. I would like the video player to be 100% of the width and height of the fixed pane. There is a horizontal pane to the left of the fixed pane as well.

I have figured out how to get the width of the window and set the initial size of the video to that, but I haven't figured out how to calculate the size of the fixed pane that it resides in or of the horizontal container next to it.

```
var width = -1;
var height = -1;

//1048,756 - too big
this.fixed1.ParentWindow.GetSize(out width, out height);

//would rather use this.fixed1.width or something of that sort.

//this.hpaned1 has an initial width that is auto-defined
//this.hpaned1 also contains a vpaned1

Console.WriteLine(width+","+height);
this.socket.WidthRequest = width; 
this.socket.HeightRequest = height;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the size of the fixed container with the "Allocation" property of the fixed container.

Like this:

```
Console.WriteLine(fixed1.Allocation.Width.ToString()+","+fixed1.Allocation.Height.ToString());
this.socket.WidthRequest = fixed1.Allocation.Width; 
this.socket.HeightRequest = fixed1.Allocation.Height;
```